# How to to select an option in an auto complete field

Tags: java, selenium, autocomplete

I have a field named "Race". When I add two characters e.g. "AS" in it, it shows me autocomplete options below which have i) Asian ii) Asian Indian etc etc options in it. The HTML for the field is as below:

```
<input name="txtRace$txtField" tabIndex="11" id="txtRace_txtField" style="width: 152px;" type="text" _events="[object Object]" hint="" _behaviors="[object Object]" AutoCompleteBehavior="[object Object]" autocomplete="off"/>  
<ul class="autocomplete_completionListElement" id="ctrltxtRace_completionListElem" style="position: absolute;" _events="[object Object]" _behaviors="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" PopupBehavior="[object Object]" GenericAnimationBehavior="[object Object]"/> Text - Empty Text Node
 <li class="autocomplete_listItem" _value="2763" __item="">
Text - Asian
<li class="autocomplete_highlightedListItem" _value="2823" __item="" _highlighted="true">
Text - Asian Indian
```

I read a code from the net and it was like:

```
idrWebElement autocomplete = idriver.findElement(By.id("txtRace_txtField"));
            autocomplete.clear();
            autocomplete.sendKeys("As");
            Thread.sleep(9000);
            WebElement autocomplete_element = idriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("xxxxxxx"));
            autocomplete_element.click();
```

---

Kindly help me as what to pass in place of xxxxxxxx.
I am using Java, Selenium, IE 10 , Win 8,

Comment: You should add html code for options.

Comment: @Evgeniy :: i have added HTML for options as well now. kindly see

Comment: I am using the following code now:
    WebElement autocomplete = idriver.findElement(By.id("txtRace_txtField"));
    autocomplete.clear();
    autocomplete.sendKeys("As");
    Thread.sleep(9000);
    WebElement autocomplete_element = idriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("898989"));
    autocomplete_element.click();
    what should i pass in place of 898989

Comment: Please edit your question, and add clarification what exactly you want to do, and which error appears.

Comment: I have edited my question, i hope it explains more about my issue. Eclipse is not showing any error. I am trying to click any value from the autocomplete dropdown that appears when i enter any two characters in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can change `findElement(By.cssSelector("xxxxxxx"));` to `findElement(By.cssSelector(".autocomplete_listItem"));` This should click on

```
<li class="autocomplete_listItem" _value="2763" __item="">
Text - Asian </li>
```

Comment: your code worked. Thanks you man.I am really thank ful to you. Can you please provide me your email ID as well? I would be grateful to you for this.
also please tell me for furture, what should i edit if i want to select the 2nd value in the autocomplete dropdown ?

Comment: You can try to change selector to `.autocomplete_highlightedListItem` as an option.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get this one:
      You can try to change selector to .autocomplete_highlightedListItem as an option

Comment: Change `.autocomplete_listItem` to `.autocomplete_highlightedListItem`

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, right click on the element which you're looking for its x path and click on 'inspect element'. 
Then, on the elements tab that has now been opened, right click on your element and 'copy as X path'

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I am using IE 10.

Comment: Press F12 with IE10 open and it will open the Web-dev tools and you can do a similar action.

Comment: @MarkRowlands: IE's f12 does not show any option to copy xpath.

Comment: With the web-dev tools open, you should see the frame overlay at the bottom of the page. Click on the Arrow button on the left, then click on the element you want to inspect. Then it will highlight the relevant HTML in the web-dev frame.

Comment: @MarkRowlands : sorry, didnt get you. I am new to selenium and this programming stuff. can you please elaborate with any example or any link that explains it?